# Scala HTTPS post including JSON input and output along with authentication

Tags: python, json, scala

I cannot find a single example of Scala HTTPS post including JSON input and output along with authentication.  I can't even find such an example in Java.  I can do this easily in Python:

```
def main(user_name, password):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

    eta_data = """{
      "contact": {
        "longitude": "-151.7200",
        "latitude": "-16.4400",
        "timestamp": "2016-04-22 15:14:55",
        "speedKnots": "15.4"
      },
      "destination": {
        "longitude": "-149.869722",
        "latitude": "-17.491667"
      }
    }"""

    r = requests.post('https://www4.demo.exactearth.com/eta', data=eta_data, auth=(user_name, password), headers=headers)
    print()
    print("eta:")
    print(r.text)
    print(r.json())
```

I'm not asking anyone to translate this to Scala for me, but how hard can this be?  Can someone please point me to an up-to-date Scala book that covers this?  Scala HTTPS post AND JSON input AND JSON output AND simple username/password authentication

Comment: have you seen scalaj-http? https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually tried to solve this task after I read your question. I've found most of the libraries are pretty complicated and use Akka in their dependencies.
I wrote that kind of call use couple of libraries and liked Play-WS more than others. Initialization a bit long (as it also using Akka) but actual usage is nice and tidy.

Down below is the code I've ended up with. Actual call is in `call` function

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

object PlayWs extends App{

  val eta_data = """{
      "contact": {
        "longitude": "-151.7200",
        "latitude": "-16.4400",
        "timestamp": "2016-04-22 15:14:55",
        "speedKnots": "15.4"
      },
      "destination": {
        "longitude": "-149.869722",
        "latitude": "-17.491667"
      }
    }"""

  def call(wsClient: StandaloneWSClient): Future[Unit] = {

    wsClient.url("http://requestb.in/ozxfttoz")
      .withAuth("username", "password", WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
      .withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json", "Accept" -> "application/json")
      .post(eta_data).map { response ⇒
        val statusText: String = response.statusText
        println("Response:")
        println(s"${response.status} $statusText")
        println(s"${response.body}")
      }
  }
  // Create Akka system for thread and streaming management
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  system.registerOnTermination {
    System.exit(0)
  }
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val wsClient = StandaloneAhcWSClient()

  call(wsClient)
    .andThen { case _ => wsClient.close() }
    .andThen { case _ => system.terminate() }

}
```

I've used standalone version and added it to project as

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ahc-ws-standalone" % "1.0.0-M6"
```

Comment: Wow, that works.  I don't know why it was so hard to find an example like this anywhere.

Comment: I am starting in Scala and also found surprisingly difficult to find detailed examples of very common task like this one!

Comment: I've found that usually, you are using some library or framework in your application and you have common tasks like this in your library/framework and should look in docs of this library on working with HTTP.

Comment: Instead of withHeaders, I used withHttpHeaders.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of POST, HTTPS, JSON input/output, and Basic Authentication in Scala can be found in the Akka HTTP docs for example here:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/host-level.html

and here:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html